# Need help in FileReader() function related script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Script getting file info like file name and path, On first file selection, script showing current file name and path. But on second file selection, first file path changed by second file path. Actually, It overwrite the first file path by second one.

```js
$('input').change(function () {
    for (var i=0, len = this.files.length; i < len; i++) {
        (function (j, self) {
            var reader = new FileReader()
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('ul').append('<li><img src="' + e.target.result + '">' + self.files[j].name + '<p class="names"></p></li>');
                var thumbName = $(".slide-thumb-name").val();
                $(".names").html(thumbName);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(self.files[j])
        })(i, this);
    }
});
```

```css
ul li{
                list-style:none;
                width:150px;
                display:inline-block;
                background-color:#f1f1f1;
                border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
                margin:3px 0;
                padding:10px;
            }
            ul li img{
                max-width:100%;
                height:20px;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" multiple class="slide-thumb-name"/>
<ul></ul>
```

See file path of both selected files:

[image]

Comment: Show us part of HTML as well. I suspect the problem is jQuery `<li>` selector.

Comment: In other words...provide a **runnable** [mcve]

Comment: @mklimek, html added

Comment: @charlietfl, now you can "Run code snippet". question updated. Thanks.

Comment: Should not you have `self.files[i]`?

Comment: not sure, @mklimek, please try it with given script.

Comment: On every change (click on browse), input val() is the last file/path you have added, that's problem (you could collect fakepaths to array, maybe), but also, since you can't get real path, not sure why you would need it at all?

Comment: `$('.names').html(thumbName)` affects all of that class in the page. Why not add the name the same way you add the other data in the new html?

Comment: @mklimek, can we add any <li> selector to get its own data for all <li>.